# Click event following mousedown and mouseup events won't occur

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I would like the following behavior.

1. "Foo" is displayed on the browser.
2. "Bar" will be shown for "Foo" if you pressed the mouse button down on "Foo".
3. "Foo" will again be shown for "Bar" if you released the button.
4. Finally "Hello" is displayed in the alert box.

I wrote the following code but the final step never happens. It seems .hide() methods are preventing onclick event from occurring.  Any idea to fix?

```
<body>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="foo">Foo</div>
    <div id="bar">Bar</div>
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
    $("#foo").show();
    $("#bar").hide();

    $("#parent").mousedown(function(){
        $("#foo").hide();
        $("#bar").show();
    });

    $("#parent").mouseup(function(){
        $("#foo").show();
        $("#bar").hide();
    });

    $("#parent").click(function(){
        alert("Hello");
    });
})
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `click` event occurrs when both `mousedown` and `mouseup` events take place. You can append your code for `click` on the end of `mouseup`

```
$("#parent").mouseup(function(){
    $("#foo").show();
    $("#bar").hide();
    alert("Hello");
});
```

Comment: But if you click outside of the div, drag your mouse into the div and then release, this will generate the alert, even though that's not a click event.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein due to his discription alert must be shown after you release the button not the actual click itself, so it may work

Answer (score 0):

> 1. 'foo' is displayed on the browser.
> 2. 'bar' will be shown for 'foo' if you pressed the mouse button down on 'foo'.
> 3. 'foo' will again be shown for 'bar' if you released the button.
> 4. Finally, "Hello" is displayed in the alert box.

There is some ambiguity by what you mean by "finally". However, one solution is to add an event listener to the `window` object after each `mousedown` event fires from `#foo`. You can then remove the listener at the end of its callback function, resulting in a 'only fire once' design.

```
on_mouseup_fn = function(e) {
    //Third condition
    $('#foo').show();
    $('#bar').hide();
    //Fourth condition
    alert("Hello!");
    $(window).off('mouseup', on_mouseup_fn);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    //First condition
    $('#bar').hide()
    $('#foo').on('mousedown', function(e) {
        //Second condition
        $(e.currentTarget).hide();
        $('#bar').show();
        //For third and fourth conditions
        $(window).on('mouseup', on_mouseup_fn);
    });
});
```

Here is a functional jsFiddle demo. Let me know if I have misinterpreted your desired element behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/n9GcS/8/